# Split relation into different output files according to data in Pig

Tags: apache-pig

Currently, my data looks like this:

```
1 A a
1 A b
2 B b
2 B c
3 A a
3 B b
3 C c
```

I want to store these in different files depending on the data in the first column. So, I would like my output to be similar to this

`1.out` contains

```
A a
A b
```

`2.out` contains

```
B b
B c
```

`3.out` contains

```
A a
B b
C c
```

Is there anyway to achieve this using Pig with/without UDFs?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm away from the cluster I use right now so I can't be 100% sure, but this should be on the right path:

```
-- Assuming myData.txt is formatted like:
-- 1 A b
-- 2 B c
-- etc.
A = LOAD 'myData.txt' USING PigStorage(' ') 
                      AS (number: int, val1: chararray, val2: chararray) ;
STORE A INTO 'myOutputDir'
        -- Stores using \t as the input separator
        USING org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.MultiStorage('myOutputDir', '0') ;
```

If you do it this way then 3 directories will be created (for 1, 2, and 3), and in those directories only files with the same number as the name of the folder will be under them.  However, in each of these directories there can be many different files (one for each mapper/reducer).  Additionally, field 0 will also have to be stored.  So, the output could look something like this:

```
--myOutputDir
|
|-->1
| |-->1-00000 #Contains 1 A a
| |-->1-00001 #Contains 1 A b
|
|-->2
| |-->2-00000 #Contains 2 B b
| |-->2-00001 #Contains 2 B c
|
|-->3
| |-->3-00000 #Contains 3 A a, 3 B b
| |-->3-00001 #Contains 3 C c
|
```

Contents of 3-00000:

```
3   A   a
3   B   b
```

However, because you know the name of the output file, you can load each output directory you created and format them as you wish:

```
-- Repeat this for all the numbers
A3 = LOAD 'myOutputDir/3' AS (number: int, val1: chararray, val2: chararray) ;
B3 = FOREACH A3 GENERATE val1, val2 ; 
STORE B3 INTO 'myOutputDir/stripped3' ;
```

So now the output will look like:

```
A    a
B    b
C    c
```

But depending on the number of mapper jobs, the data can still be split among several files.  If they need to be all in the same file I'd just recommend writing a script that merges the parts together.  I use something like this (but obviously more general):

```
import os
import glob
partfiles = os.path.join('myOutputDir', 'stripped3', 'part-m-[0-9]*')
with open('part-m-COMPLETE-3', 'w') as outfile:
    for myfile in glob.glob(partfiles):
        with open(myfile, 'r') as infile:
            for line in infile:
                outfile.write(line)
```

Comment: Thank you! This works like a charm. Wouldn't have figured out that I need to use `org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.MultiStorage`