# How to Split data using parameters in pig

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

I have below data for each department

```
1,IT,100
2,HR,244
3,AC,345
4,IT,654
5,HR,856
6,AC,545
7,IT,769
8,AC,423
9,HR,908
```

I need to split data into dept's based on department name 
code :

```
data = LOAD '/user/dept_data.txt' USING PigStorage(',') as (id:int,dept:chararray,count:int);
split data into (IT_data  if dept=='IT'),
                (HR_data  if dept=='HR'),
                (AC_data  if dept=='AC');
```

Its working fine however now I need to make it generic so that If any new dept comes then 
I won't need to make any changes to the code.
something like this :

```
split data into ('$dept'_data  if dept=='$dept');
```

I tried to modify above code as follows :

```
data = LOAD '/user/dept_data.txt' USING PigStorage(',') as (id:int,dept:chararray,count:int);

depts = foreach data generate dept as dept;

distinct_dept= distinct depts;

split data into 'distinct_dept.dept'_data if dept=='distinct_dept.dept';
```

Its not working 
how can I achieve the same?

Comment: Possible duplicate [Split data in PIG](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17537470/split-relation-into-different-output-files-according-to-data-in-pig)

Comment: If objective is to store the data after split then the above link should help, if its required for further processing to generate the KPI then we can group by dept and use it further.